# how to combine R data frames with non-exact criteria (greater/less than condition)

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have to combine two R data frames which have trade and quote information. Like a join, but based on a timestamp in seconds. I need to match each trade with the most recent quote. There are many more quotes than trades.

I have this table with stock quotes. The Timestamp is in seconds:

```
+--------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Symbol | Timestamp |  bid  |  ask  |
+--------+-----------+-------+-------+
| IBM    |        10 | 132   | 133   |
| IBM    |        20 | 132.5 | 133.3 |
| IBM    |        30 | 132.6 | 132.7 |
+--------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

And these are trades:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
| Symbol | Timestamp | quantity | price |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
| IBM    |        25 |      100 | 132.5 |
| IBM    |        31 |       80 | 132.7 |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

I think a native R function or dplyr could do it - I've used both for basic purposes but not sure how to proceed here. Any ideas?

So the trade at 25 seconds should match with the quote at 20 seconds, and the trade @31 matches the quote @30, like this:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| Symbol | Timestamp | quantity | price |  bid  |  ask  |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| IBM    |        25 |      100 | 132.5 | 132.5 | 133.3 |
| IBM    |        31 |       80 | 132.7 | 132.6 | 132.7 |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Will *Timestamp* in *quotes* table always be in increments of 10?

Comment: No, I was just simplifying as an example. They're actually in milliseconds.

Comment: Can you edit *Timestamp* fields to show what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider merging on a calculated field by increments of 10. Specifically, calculate a column for multiples of 10 in both datasets, and merge on that field with *Symbol*.

Below `transform` and `within` are used to assign and de-assign the helper field, *mult10*. In this use case, both base functions are interchangeable:

```
final_df <- transform(merge(within(quotes, mult10 = floor(Timestamp / 10) * 10),
                            within(trades, mult10 = floor(Timestamp / 10) * 10),
                            by=c("Symbol", "mult10"),
                      multi10 = NULL)
```

Now if the 10 multiple does not suffice for your needs, adjust to level you require such as 15, 5, 2, etc.

```
within(quotes, mult10 <- floor(Timestamp / 15) * 15)

within(quotes, mult10 <- floor(Timestamp / 5) * 5)

within(quotes, mult10 <- floor(Timestamp / 2) * 2)
```

Even more, you may need to use the reverse, `floor` or `ceiling` for both data sets respectively to calculate highest multiple of quote's *Timestamp* and lowest multiple of trade's *Timestamp*:

```
within(quotes, mult10 <- ceiling(Timestamp / 15) * 15)

within(trades, mult10 <- floor(Timestamp / 5) * 5)
```